# Using an app access token, why do i need publish_stream permission instead of just publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm using an app access token to write to a facebook user's wall (using the facebook graph toolkit in asp.net). i've found that the process works fine if i have publish_stream permission but fails if i only have publish_actions. i would prefer to work only with publish_actions to avoid the second screen permission request.

this issue seems to go against the fb docs which state "Moving forward, we recommend that apps only ask for publish_actions, as this permission encompasses the other two and we want to simplify the model." (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/)

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced and overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/).

It says-

> publish_actions will now include basic publish_stream permissions (including posting on a user's timeline, posting photos/videos, commenting on and liking content), which will appear on the first Auth Dialog screen. With this change, apps that were previously granted publish_stream do not need to request publish_actions.

as you said, BUT-

> If you need specific capabilities like posting to a friend's timeline or to groups, you will still need to request publish_stream, which appears on a second screen where users can also opt out.